# a code for clearing certain cells in certain columns based on a text value in a certain cell

Tags: excel, vba

i want help with a code that will clear cells F10:F34 - H10:H34 - I10:I34 when a certain text is choosen from a drop list in M2
i found alot of VBA codes that actually doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

maybe this helps:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H5")) Is Nothing Then

        If Me.Range("H5").Value = "something" Then
            Me.Range("F10:F34").Value = ""
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it didnt work mike i dont know why nothing happens when i choose the specific value from the drop down list


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("M2")) Is Nothing Then

        If Me.Range("M2").Value = "Êã ÇáÇáÛÇÁ" Then
            Me.Range("F10:F34").Value = "0"
        End If

    End If
End Sub

Comment: does the drop donw really change the value in cell M2 or is the drop down an aciivex form element?